# What is transient frequency response in LTSpice?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, ltspice

In LTSpice there is an analysis tab called the Transient frequency response.  I have no clue of how to use it and what it does.  Please let me know how to use it.

[image]

It's asking for an analyser. Is the required analyser available within the LTSpice or it is talking about some external analyser?

Comment: *fra* is a frequency response analysis element you need to stick into the circuit model. It’s available from one of the component palettes. Nothing external. The analysis is a transient one, but repeated at multiple frequencies to get the frequency-domain response plot.

Comment: Why not look in the help? F1 to get that, add 'fra' to the search bar, select associated item, read it. At the bottom it says *`See the examples that are part of the LTspice release typically installed in directory %LOCALAPPDATA%\LTspice\examples\Educational\FRA\`*. So there are even some concrete examples to use.